# Why is my entry only recognized only when I put ::withTrashed() on the model

Tags: php, eloquent, soft-delete

So I am creating an user, on creation I set the deleted_at date a hour ahead so it softdeletes if the time passes, but the problem is that eloquent is already taking the entry as softdeleted.How do I fix this without making the deleted_at null.

This works:

```
$user = User::withTrashed()->where('id',15)->first();
```

And this does not:

```
$user = User::where('id',15)->first(); //returns null
```

This is my code for setting the deleted_at time on creation in the model file:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->deleted_at = now()->addHour();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soft deletions aren't made for this; the date is simply a record of when it was deleted. Laravel's queries just look for a NULL value in `deleted_at`; nothing fancier.

What you want is your own [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#global-scopes) you can apply to the model. You could use `deleted_at` in it, but you're probably better off with something like `available_until` to keep them separate.

Comment: Thanks! Adding available_until to the model, on creation I set it an hour from now, then I put the condition in the apply function in the global scope available_until > now() , I think this should work, I will try it.